# saving object out of html to Parse with javascript

Tags: javascript, html, parsing

When I run this code it fails to save the newEntry in Parse. When I uncomment the first save attempt it works: After entering some text to the textfield and pressing submit, it saves "why needed?", then the newEntry and "why needed?" again (3 new objects saved in Parse database):

```
<!doctype html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">

<title>In and out test with Parse</title>
<meta name="inandout" content="inandout">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/reset.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/styles.css">
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.parsecdn.com/js/parse-latest.js"></script>
</head>

<body>

<script type="text/javascript">

Parse.initialize("5xxIFHDqTXlinKWhrrqjOq7VkfDawBGejxZ0LzvA", "dqPpBU4bDykgelEEt0qSFy2GVk135kyGASjW9UhV");

  /*
  var Daten = Parse.Object.extend("Daten");
  var daten = new Daten();
  daten.save({Eintrag: "why needed?"}, {
     success: function(object) {
    $(".success").show();
     },
     error: function(model, error) {
    $(".error").show();
  }
  });
  */

 </script>

 <div id="main">
 <h1>Input to be saved to Parse (Class Daten / Row: Eintrag)</h1>

    <div>
        <form onSubmit="handleClick()">
        Eintrag:<br>
        <input id="wert" type="text" name="eintrag">
        <br><br>
        <input type="submit">
        </form>
    </div>

<div style="display:none" class="error">
  Looks like there was a problem saving the object.
</div>

<div style="display:none" class="success">
  <p>Objekt gespeichert!</p>
</div>

</div>

<script>

function handleClick(){

    var newEntry = document.getElementById("wert").value;

    var Daten = Parse.Object.extend("Daten");
    var daten = new Daten();
    daten.save({Eintrag: newEntry}, {
    success: function(object) {
    $(".success").show();
    },
    error: function(model, error) {
    $(".error").show();
  }
});
}
</script>



</body>

</html>
```

I just want to save the newEntry in Parse. How can I do that?

Have tried a lot of different things without success. The Parse documentation only says that the save function has to be "somewhere after" the Parse.initialize...

Comment: What happens when it *is* commented?   Your error block shows?

Comment: No. The error block just quickly flashes up and disappears again.